# HMVC model cannot be loaded SAYS Message: Undefined property:

Tags: php, codeigniter, model, module, hmvc

hi i am currently working on a second module of my hmvc file and there comes an error that i think it wont load the models of this module. the previous modules models, works fine. what may be the error of this one? here is my codes.

error

```
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: CI::$lEmploymentStatus_Model

Filename: MX/Controller.php

Line Number: 59

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\TLC_HR\application\third_party\MX\Controller.php
Line: 59
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\TLC_HR\application\modules\EmploymentStatus\Controllers\EmploymentStatus.php
Line: 43
Function: __get

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\TLC_HR\index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once
```

controller - EmploymentStatus.php

```
<?php

class EmploymentStatus extends MY_Controller{

    public function __construct(){

        parent::__construct();
    }

// VIEW REDIRECTING /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public function index(){

    $data['content_view'] = 'EmploymentStatus/empstat_read';
    $this->templates->admin_template($data);

    }

    public function add_view(){

    $data['content_view'] = 'EmploymentStatus/add_view';
    $this->templates->admin_template($data);

    }


// CREATE /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public function create(){


        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->model('EmploymentStatus_Model');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('ES_NAME','Name','trim|required|min_length[2]|max_length[20]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('ES_DESCRIPTION','Description','trim|required|max_length[50]');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){

            $this->add_view();
        }else{

            if($query = $this->lEmploymentStatus_Model->insert()){
                $this->add_view();
            }else{
                $this->add_view();
            }

        }

    }

}

?>
```

model - EmploymentStatus_Model.php

```
<?php

class EmploymentStatus_Model extends CI_Model{

/////  CREATE /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public function insert(){

        $input = array(
                'ES_NAME' => $this->input->post('ES_NAME'),
                'ES_DESCRIPTION' => $this->input->post('ES_DESCRIPTION')
                );
        $insert = $this->db->insert('employment_status',$input);
        return $insert;
    }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

it works perfectly fine. It just have a typo.

`if($query = $this->lEmploymentStatus_Model->insert()){
                $this->add_view();`

lEmploymentStatus must be EmploymentStatus